# Remove a space page when generate PDF page

Tags: html, css, pdf, dompdf

I am generating PDF using the DOMPDF library with Laravel. I need the page to be an exact size, in this case 7.5 cm x 10 cm. I created a div and I need this div to occupy 100% horizontally and vertically of the page, but when the pdf is generated it always has a margin underneath and the second page is created. I need it to be just one page. If I decrease the div size to 6 cm high it works

```css
 @page {
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
            size: 7.5cm 10cm landscape !important;
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        body, html { 
            size: 7.5cm 10cm landscape !important;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
        }
.borda {
            border: thin solid black;
        }
```

```html
<div class="borda" style="height: 7cm; width: 10cm; background-color: lightgreen;">
    This is a DIV. How to make the div occupy 100% of the screen in pdf:
</div>
```

```
<div class="borda" style="height: 7cm; width: 10cm; background-color: lightgreen;">
    This is a DIV. How to make the div occupy 100% of the screen in pdf:
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try using 100vh instead of your 7cm

Comment: I tryed to use 100vh, but the content appear in 3 pages and I wanted that the content appear in 1 page